# How do I Restore Navigation State on Startup (Jetpack Compose)?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation

When I start up my app I want it to be able to restore the user's last session if it wasn't completed. How do I restore the navigation backstack while using Jetpack Compose?

My application presents educational sessions, with pages being generated dynamically. Back/up navigation works fine.

```
@Composable
fun SessionScreenLayout(
    pageIndex: Int,
    mainViewModel: MainViewModel,
    ) {
    ...
}
```

If a session is not completed when the app shuts down then I manually store that session and I want to be able to restore it when the user starts up again. **Importantly I want back navigation to navigate sequentially backwards through my Session pages, after I have restored a session**

I've tried populating the backstack but creating a new NavBackStackEntry seems to have 2 options. First doesn't work because the new NavBackStackEntry has the same id as the currentBackStackEntry. After populating the back stack I navigate to the last page and that works fine. but if I navigate backwards the page doesn't recompose properly:

```
val entry = NavBackStackEntry(
    entry = currentBackStackEntry!!,
    arguments = Bundle().apply {
        ...
    }
)
navController.backQueue.addLast(entry)
navController.navigate(Screen.SessionScreen.withIndex(userSession.highestPageIndexViewed))
```

Else have tried using NavBackStackEntry.create():

```
val entry = NavBackStackEntry.create(
   hostLifecycleState = ?,
   viewModelStoreProvider = ?,
   ...
)
navController.backQueue.addLast(entry)
navController.navigate(Screen.SessionScreen.withIndex(userSession.highestPageIndexViewed))
```

With this I need the "viewModel" and "lifecycleOwner" private fields values from the navController for the constructor AFAIK. Without those I'm getting an exception. Again the last navigation works, but when I go back:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call setViewModelStore() on your NavHostController before accessing the ViewModelStore of a navigation graph.
```

How do I get this working?